# Highcharts export menu does not show up fully

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I made a Highchart with height of 200px.

It seemed to work fine, but export menu does not fully show up when i click on it, i can not export XLS or CSV.
Sadly i can not change the height, i need it to be 200px for my project.

[image: broken export context menu demonstration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the overflow, without seeing your html it's hard to know what element to select but assuming you're doing something like this

```
<div id="chart-container" style="height: 200px"></div>
```

You can add a CSS class like this

```
#chart-container > .highcharts-container {
  overflow: visible!important;
}
```

As specified by this GitHub issue https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7671

This issue may of been hard to find due to the misspelled title, but please search the repos issues before asking

**EDIT:**

In your case the element under your container has a class called `.highcharts-fixed` so changing the code above to reflect that, makes it work

```
#container > .highcharts-fixed {
  overflow: visible!important;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f3vh9prk/)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did exactly as you wrote but i can not make it work. https://jsfiddle.net/aty7eu5w/2/ there is the demo on highcharts website and i changed only height and added CSS. i cannot figure out what else it needs :/

Comment: @GeorgeShalvashvili apologise for the late reply, I went home after I wrote that answer, I've updated it for your case